# Showing to user progress while parallel running process in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, progress-bar

My goal is to make silent install of JRE to client without any ASK toll bar or redirecting to oracle after installing... So , I make batch file like :

```
@echo off 
setlocal
echo Installing JRE started. It will take about 40 seconds. Please wait...
START /WAIT jre-8u31-windows-i586.exe /s /L C:\\jre8_31.log
START /WAIT http://example.co.il/
EXIT
```

It is working as required, but the process take about the minute and I want to add some animation for user, like progress bar.
I'm java programmer without deep knowledge of bat/script programming, so I hope to get suggestions for my problem. Also the solution must be without need for user to download any added resources.

Comment: You should remove the solution from the question and post it as an answer, and then accept it. You may have to wait a while (hours? days?) before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
I found the solution, thanks to EL MANO:

```
@echo off
title Loading... By El Mano
color 0a
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
:Loading
set load=%load%()
cls
echo.
echo Loading... Please Wait...
echo ----------------------------------------
echo %load% 
echo ----------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto Done
rem You can set the number of ()'s as whatever you rem want but remember: in your "loading box" you rem need 2 spaces for every () because "()" takes up rem 2 spaces. The above box has 40 spaces, so rem twenty repeats, adding 1 () every repeat.
goto Loading
:Done
echo.
pause
rem *your action here*
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

The /S is specifying a "Silent" installation. Try executing the command below from a CMD prompt. That may show additional choices. If you are lucky this command may show that you have choices other than /S such as /Q, /QB, /QN, /QB, etc.

```
jre-8u31-windows-i586.exe /?
```

Comment: all of this configurations leads to redirecting to Oracle website, and this what I don't want. So I need to make silent installation.

Comment: I guess you will have to wait for someone with Oracle experience. We do this with SQL with an 'Answer File'. In that file we can specify various levels of interaction with the user. I use: QUIET="False" and QUIETSIMPLE="True". This results in no user interaction, but progress is shown.

Comment: What you mean when say QUIET="False"? Can you past all command for my case? Thank you